# Dynamic color change in xml?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, uiview, android-layout

I have a xml layout, i assigned color like android:textColor="#800080"; is there any way to change the color for this parameter dynamically while the app is running by user input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change text color of a view dynamically like this `view.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#234435"));`

Comment: it looks like this solved your problem. Thus, you should accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can change text color of a view dynamically like this `view.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255,0,0));`

also `view.setTextColor(Color.Red)`